# How to make H2 db display a number instead of date/interval

Tags: sql, h2

Is it possible to make H2 db display a number instead of date/interval to get the same short answer as oracle/mysql?

Running this sql in oracle /H2 console:

```
select trunc(sysdate+5)  - trunc(sysdate) noOfDays from dual;
```

Response in H2:

```
NOOFDAYS  
INTERVAL '5 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
```

Response in oracle:

```
NOOFDAYS
5
```

I´m looking to get the short 5 from H2 as I got form Oracle.
We have followed http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility
with oracle compability mode set, but does not get the described "DATE data type is treated like TIMESTAMP(0) data type."

To_Char won't work as the interval must work round months. We have tried changing the sql , different dialects but no success.

Comment: Well, Oracle doesn't return an `interval` in your example to begin with. It returns a `number`. Try `select (current_timestamp + interval '5' day) - current_timestamp from dual` in Oracle - **that** will return an `interval`

Comment: Ok I see, thank you! But if I want H2 to return a number instead of a interval/date-format?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cast it to decimal:

```sql
select cast(trunc(sysdate+5) - trunc(sysdate) as decimal) noOfDays from dual;
```

In H2 it should cast interval 5 days to number 5, and in Oracle the cast should have no effect since expression is already a number